# Прошу небольшого объяснения по функциям на Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, уважаемые участники форума. Недавно начала изучать язык Python, сейчас нахожусь на тебе "Функции". Все идет вроде бы хорошо, но я столкнулась с проблемой: я не понимаю, что делает return в функциях. Я поняла, что он возвращает получившееся значение, но куда он возвращает и т.д - не понятно. Кто бы мог мне помочь с данным вопросом? Буду очень благодарна!!!

Comment: https://younglinux.info/python/return

Comment: return возвращает значение (и управление) тому, кто вызвал эту функцию

Comment: Ну, вот вернул return это значение, куда он вернул это?

Comment: https://youtu.be/TX0-gdBrhW8 там он конечно про Си говорит, но концепция стека вызовов и возврата управления с передачей результата везде одинаковая.

Answer (score 0):

https://younglinux.info/python/return

Функции могут передавать какие-либо данные из своих тел в основную ветку программы.
Говорят, что функция `возвращает значение`.
В большинстве языков программирования, в том числе `Python`,
выход из функции и передача данных `в то место, откуда она была вызвана`, выполняется оператором `return`.

Если интерпретатор Питона, выполняя тело функции, встречает `return`,
то он "забирает" значение, `указанное после этой команды`, и "уходит" из функции.

В данном примере в основную ветку из функции возвращается значение локальной переменной `new_text`.
Не сама переменная, а ее значение, в данном случае – какую-то строку,
полученную в результате каких-то вычислений и присваивает это значение переменной `value`.

```
def myFunc(text):
    new_text = f'Hello {text}'
    return new_text

value = myFunc('Мария')
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если проще:
есть вы и ваш ребенок. Вы ему говорите, вот тебе деньги(параметры функции, которые мы ей передаем, например) иди купи хлеба.
Он берет деньги и покупает хлеб (функция берет параметры и что-то вычисляет) и приносит хлеб вам для дальнейших действий )))
соответственно можно присвоить переменной возвращаемое значение функции:
бутерброд = def получить_хлеб(деньги)

```
def get_anything(param):
    return param * 2
anything = get_anything(param)
```